# ms-access 2003 form data entry stopped working

Tags: ms-access-2003

I have a form with a subform that at one point allowed for data to be modified.  It now gives an audible "bing" when I try to change a field.  My save cmd button now displays the error "The command or action 'SaveRecord' isn't available now."  My form on the switchboard is set to Command: Open in Edit Mode, both the Form and subForm are set to Data Entry "Yes" on the Data tab.  What am I missing that would cause the fields to not allow update adn the save command to no longer work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was working before?

I had a similar misterious problem with textbox zoom that a one point in time started generating an error,  only in one form.
The solution was to create a new blank form and copy / paste all controls from the defective to the new blank one, same operation for the code in the VBA and everything was back to normal.

You can try do do this and , if the problem persist, then is something in your code or in the form properties. Hope this will help

Comment: Fedlz. Thanks, that is what I ended up doing.  Appreciate the comments.